# update panel is not working properly

Tags: asp.net

I have an update panel. inside this panel, there are two controls a label and a dropdown.

I'm changing the label's value using javascript. the dropdown has a selectIndexChanged event.

whenever this event fires it clears off the label's value i set using javascript.

What's going wrong here?

--------Edit------------

Thanks for the responses. I understand that since label is not a user entry field the value is not retained on postback. Let me explain my situation.

There is a form

It has a textbox, an icon, and a dropdown that has an event. All these items are present inside an update panel.

Clicking on the icon will open popup. the text box value is populated from the popup using javascript.

I dont want the user to edit this textbox's value. So i changed readonly. It doesn't retain teh value.

is there a way to make this textbox disabled and still retain the value on postback?

Comment: Are you sure you're setting it to readonly and not disabled? If you set the textbox value to readonly using javascript, the value should be retained. Disabled, though, and it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label is not an "input" control so values you set won't be sent to the server, the ViewState mecanism restore the value on postback. This has nothing to do with the UpdatePanel.

**EDIT**

If you need the value to persist you can use a Label + a HiddenField. The hidden field would make it to the server because is an "input" control and you can set the Label value on server side.

Something like this

**client side**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

...

document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'test';"
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value= 'test';"
```

**server side (you execute this logic on postback)**

```
Label1.Text = HiddenField1.Value
```

Comment: Hi Claudio, thanks for the response. I want this label to be a read only field. I dont want the user to change the value. The value is populated from a popup window. I tried changing it to a textbox with readonly/disabled. It doesn't retain the value. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash: I've added a possible solution

Comment: @Vivek Chandraprakash: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing a label via javascript, the server has no idea that you did that. Remember, a label is simply a span element. You do not send the *entire* page back to the server everytime you post back, you only send form elements. If you want the server to know about this, you'll need to put the change into a hidden form element (for example).